# how to increase number of product on homepage in magento

Tags: php, magento

i am new in magento and reading a file toolbar.phtml 
and file path is E:\wamp\www\meditrust_mage\app\design\frontend\default\medi\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml......

in this file i found this peace of code,and dont know where to change product limit on homepage.i want to show all products on homepage and want to increse dropdown value to differnt level like 10,20,30...50 and so on. how to do this.

```
 <div class="limiter">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the settings in the Admin area. Go to `System-> Configuration->Catalog->Frontend` and change the number per page options and default.

```
Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values
Products per Page on Grid Default Value
```

Reference: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-default-amount-of-products-in-products-listing.html

Comment: Wc..Glad to help you :)

Comment: can u please suggest any good book for beginner in magento ? or any way to learn magento

Comment: Best source according to me --> http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki --> http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base --> http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/index/pages/ Rest you can ask here.

Comment: helpfull reference ... i will follow it vishwas